# Generating a series of non-random numbers with a maximum sum of 100

Tags: ruby

I am working on a program that has a component that will generate simulated demographic numbers for various hypothetical jurisdictions.

The methods I have set up to generate each subset of demographics are dependent on some other variables, but generally, most jurisdictions are supposed to look something like:

```
White - 65%
Latino - 20%
African-American - 10%
Other - 5%
```

Of course, this isn't always the case. In some scenarios, white may be well under 50% with either Latino or AA being the most significant, but those are more edge cases. But in general that's usually about the balance.

So I am trying to figure out how to generate each demographic, which again is fed from different variables, mostly independently, but ensuring the number always adds up to 100.

I had thought about generating white first, since it's typically the largest, and then just creating a generator where Latino% = 100 - white%*.35 (.35 is just an example here), and so forth, but this creates a situation in which white would always be the plurality, which I don't necessarily want to happen.

So I am a bit stuck. I imagine this is as much a math problem as a Ruby problem. As a non-math person (who, as they have delved into programming, wishes they had paid better attention in class), I'd appreciate any guidance here.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, each demographic depends on some external variables. What you could do then is

```
whites  = getWhites();         // could be anything really
aa      = getAA();
latinos = getLatinos();

sum = whites + aa + latinos;

whites  = whites / sum * 100;
aa      = aa / sum * 100;
latinos = latinos / sum * 100;
```

This guarantees that they always sum up to 100

Edit: The code is pseudocode (not ruby), assuming floating point data type

Comment: Thank you! This certainly works. I'll need to figure out if it messes too much with my original generation formulas (in terms of balances), but I can tweak that on my end if there are issues.

Comment: nice solution @Saad. You might need to throw `.to_f` on the end of sum in each of the last three lines to ensure the division works correctly. Ruby assumes that if you do division of integers that you want an integer as a result. Not the case here.

Comment: What is the point of producing a non-random sample in a simulation?

Comment: @sam I'm not familiar with ruby syntax, I wrote the code as pseudocode. I have edited the answer

Comment: 1. Ruby does not require semi-colons at the ends of lines. 2. Ruby uses snake-case for the names of variables. 3. If `whites = 254; latinos = 71; aa = 34`, then `sum = whites + latinos + aa #=> 359`, then `whites  = whites / sum * 100 #=> 0`, `aa = aa / sum * 100 #=> 0`, `latinos = latinos / sum * 100 #=> 0`, so `whites + latinos + aa #=> 0`. 4. You forgot `other`. Pseudocode is unacceptable when the language is given in a tag. Downvote is mine.

Comment: @CarySwoveland - Well, they're random in the sense they are generated using the rand() method, but also not truly random because I have tilted the scales on what number rand() is going to spit out. So...just depends on how you define random. I just felt if it was truly random it may have changed the answer I got (but maybe not).

Answer (score 3):

First specify a *cumulative distribution function* (CDF).

```
DIST = { white: 0.65, latino: 0.85, aa: 0.95, other: 1.00 }
```

Note that

```
DIST[:white] - 0             #=> 0.65
DIST[:latino] - DIST[:white] #=> 0.20
DIST[:aa] - DIST[:latino]    #=> 0.10
DIST[:other] - DIST[:aa]     #=> 0.05
```

Now create a method to (pseudo-) randomly select one person from the population and return their ethnicity.

```
def select_one
   rn = rand
   DIST.find { |_k, v| rn <= v }.first
end
```

Try it.

```
10.times { p select_one }
:white
:aa
:latino
:white
:white
:white
:white
:white
:white
:latino
```

Now write a method to return a random sample of size `n`.

```
def draw_sample(n)
  n.times.with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |_, h| h[select_one] += 1 }
end
```

Try it.

```
10.times { p draw_sample(100) }
{:white=>66, :latino=>21, :aa=>9,  :other=>4}
{:white=>72, :latino=>14, :aa=>11, :other=>3}
{:white=>61, :latino=>19, :aa=>14, :other=>6}
{:white=>64, :latino=>25, :aa=>8,  :other=>3}
{:white=>69, :latino=>19, :aa=>4,  :other=>8}
{:white=>68, :latino=>17, :aa=>9,  :other=>6}
{:white=>68, :latino=>16, :aa=>12  :other=>4}
{:white=>51, :latino=>27, :aa=>10, :other=>12}
{:white=>69, :latino=>23, :aa=>6,  :other=>2}
{:white=>63, :latino=>19, :aa=>14, :other=>4}
```

(Note the order of the keys above varied; I reordered them to improve readability.)

On could alternatively write

```
def draw_sample(n)
  n.times.map { select_one }.tally
end
```

though this has the disadvantage that it creates an intermediate array.

See [Kernel#rand](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-rand), the form of [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) that takes an argument (the *default value*, here zero) and [Enumerable#tally](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally).